# Assimp + COLLADA models with bones = incorrect vertex positions

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, collada, assimp

I'm using Assimp to load COLLADA models created and exported with Blender v2.7, but I noticed a funny issue. Whenever I apply (in Blender) transformations to a mesh in "Object mode" instead of "Edit mode", the resultant transformations apply not to the vertices I read from the Assimp importer data, but to the `mParent` matrix of the `aiNode` that contains the mesh.

That's not really a problem since I can read the vertices of the mesh and then multiply them by the `aiNode`'s `mParent` matrix to obtain the vertices of the mesh in the correct position.

The problem arrives whenever I try to do the same with meshes that have bones. I don't know why, but in this case, the transformations that I have applied in "Object mode" aren't applied neither to the vertices I read directly from the mesh nor to the `aiNode`'s `mParent` matrix.

Can someone explain to me how to get the correct positions of the vertices of a mesh with bones using Assimp and COLLADA models?

Comment: I assume this involves OpenGL / GLSL somehow? You speak of multiplying matrices and incorrect vertex positions, but have given no relevant implementation details. My hunch, after seeing this problem over and over, is that you are not dealing with integer vertex attributes correctly.

Comment: It's not that. The problem is that I can't find the object transformations that Assimp's importer is supposed to be loading when loading meshes that have bones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating the collada importer/exporter can solve this.